# Ocultar id en consulta php?

Tags: php

Hola queridos amigos tengo un problema con una consulta php que hace una llamada al archivo advanceplus.php, lo que sucede es que necesito ocultar el nombre del archivo advanceplus.php y su id=1, el codigo va de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="advanceplus.php?id=1" onclick="return confirm('Estas seguro que quieres continuar?');">Go Now!
```

lo que necesito ocultar es la direccion original de la llamada al archivo, para ser mas concreto esta parte del url: advanceplus.php?id=1 como puedo hacer para que no se vea la url?, desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Hola, ¿Por qué quieres ocultarla?

Comment: Podrías intentar usar algún medio sencillo de encriptación, cuando envíes la url va encriptada y cuando la recibas la desencriptas

Comment: Hola y dime querido amigo como puedo hacer eso? lo siento pero solo se un poco de programacion, bueno lo basico jeje, saludos!

Comment: Saludos. La opción que proporne @tutuyale es la adecuada (mira aqui https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-encrypt.php busca "omidbahrami1990 at gmail dot com" -sin las comillas") necesitas secured_encrypt y secured_decrypt (algo como cifrado y descifrado seguro respectivamente). El resultado de secured_encrypt lo pasarias en 'id' y lo que llegue a donde direccionas lo pasas a secured_decrypt ; recuerda esto es texto; por tanto deveras realizar la conversion para cifrar y al decifrar.

Comment: Hola amigo lo siento pero no se que hacer jeje, es una lastima no tener tanto conocimiento php, saludos!

Comment: No respondiste la primera pegunta: ¿Por qué quieres ocultarla?

Comment: Hola querido amigo lo que sucede es que cuando se hace la llamada directamente al archivo advanceplus.php?id=1, mi script proporciona mas bux aunque el usuario no tenga bux, los bux es una moneda virtual de mi web, y lo que necesito es ocultarla para que no me hackeen bux, saludos

Comment: No entiendo por qué ocultarlo tampoco. Esto se podría hacer con el mod rewrite de Apache, por ejemplo, pero no entiendo como para qué

Comment: Deberías hacer un chequeo desde PHP para determinar si el script tiene o no que correr (dependiendo del usuario). Ocultar la URL no es una solución, estás planteando mal el problema.

Comment: O aplicar en tu desarrollo un enrutador, como en los MVC. Tienes muchos ejemplos sobre mvc y varios frameworks que hacen eso.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si un usuario copia el enlace, aún con la ID codificada? Que va a obtener los `bux` de cualquier forma. Deberías hacer una validación en PHP para determinar si aplicas o no los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hace algo como esto, haber si te sirve..

```
<?php
$_id = 1;
$id_encoded = base64_encode($_id);
// resultado: MQ==
?>

<a href="advanceplus.php?id=<?= $id_encoded?>">ok</a>

<?php
//resultado link: advanceplus.php?id=MQ==
$id_decoded = base64_decode($GET['id']);
//id identificado 1
?>
```

[image: Código de ejemplo]

Comment: Hola cuando coloco el codigo si lo encripta pero al darle click en ok no se desencripta como puedo hacer para que funcione

Comment: base64_encode(); // para codificar y enviar el valor </br>
base64_decode(); // para decodificar y utilizar el valor.

Comment: Hola hector no se porque no me funciona el codigo, no se que estoy haciendo mal, saludos, yo coloque al principio de la pagina el codigo de encode y al final de la pagina el codigo de decode, creo que es asi? saludos

Comment: No se decodifica al dar click, se decodifica al recibirlo en el servidor.

Comment: pero yo veo que el si lo codifica porque me sale esto: advanceplus.php?id=MQ== , pero cuando le doy click me sale una pagina en blanco osea no lleva al id=1 saludos

Comment: En esa pagina en blanco es donde debe decodificar, es decir, donde recibe la información.

Comment: En este caso creo es en advanceplus.php y lo recibes con $_GET['id']

Comment: ahh ya, creo que ya entendi, osea debo de colocar decode codigo en la pagina del script osea en la pagina en blanco?, saludos!

Comment: Se codifica donde das click para enviar el id y se decodifica donde recibes el id con $_GET['id']

Comment: Hola coloque el codigo de encode en el principio de la pagina del archivo donde aparece el link y en el archivo advanceplus.php coloque al principio de la pagina el codigo de decode pero aun asi me aparece en blanco, no se porque, saludos!

Comment: hazlo sin code decode, haber si aparece en blanco

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo como lo dice la respuesta del compañero pero debes agregar el urlencode para que no tengas conflictos de codificación

```
<a href="advanceplus.php?id=<?=urlencode($id_encoded) ?>">ok</a>
```

Y en el get

```
$id_decoded = base64_decode(urldecode($GET['id'])) ;
```